# Change IPv4 IPs and other values on Windows 7 or 8 using python

Tags: python

I need to change following 5 values :

[image]

I have researched and found that I can Use "WMI" but that do not looks promising. Ipaddress module also looks like I would not be able to change all 5 values, https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html

Do I have any other option?

Comment: Win32api for Python is what I think you need.

Comment: or `subprocess.Popen` aaaand `Popen('netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1', shell=True)`.. But yea since we're doing things programatically, use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/)

Comment: No mention of how to change preferred and alternative DNS :(

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84ab53c2-1188-494d-9aae-028eafe05800/how-do-i-programatically-change-from-dhcp-to-static-ip-and-back-again?forum=vcgeneral